# IAT Hooking, QT library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, qt, code-injection

I have a .dll injected into the address space of another process.  The target app uses the QT library.  I can insert a detour so that each time the QT function 
?rowsInserted@QListView@@MAEXABVQModelIndex@@HH@Z is called my function is called instead and then the call passed on.  However, how do I get access to the parameters passed into ?rowsInserted@QListView@@MAEXABVQModelIndex@@HH@Z?  Is this name garbled, in which case what is it normally?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually you can't correctly detour a function unless you know exactly its signature (and calling convention for x86 applications). Otherwise you'll just crash the app. Just look at the Qt docs and find this method's description. And surely, you need to check that this is actually exported from dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the function is probably [`QListView::rowsInserted(const QModelIndex &, int, int)`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qlistview.html#rowsInserted). The parameters are listed in the function reference.

Comment: Thanks Greg, how do you work it out or is it just a case of this is the closest?  Also, is the name garbled?  Another question which sprang to mind was would IDA be the one responsible for garbling the name?  Again thanks.

Comment: The mangled name started with `rowsInserted@QListView@@`, and I knew that MSVC mangles the name in that way for a function called `rowsInserted` in the `QListView` class. Turns out there's only one function by that name. See [Name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) for more information on why the compiler does this (it's not IDA).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `undname` tool to undecorate function calls. It ships with Visual C++.
Raymond Chen blogged about it: [Undecorating names to see why a function can't be found](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/29/9255240.aspx)

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1>undname ?rowsInserted@QListView@@MAEXABVQModelIndex@@HH@Z

Undecoration of :- "?rowsInserted@QListView@@MAEXABVQModelIndex@@HH@Z"
is :- "protected: virtual void __thiscall QListView::rowsInserted(class QModelIndex const &,int,int)"
```